# delete some char set from the last column linux

Tags: sed, awk

I want to the delete everything after hyphen "e-" in the last column output..

Below is what my output looks like..

```
# awk '/out: OpenSSL/ { gsub( /[][]|out:/ , "" ) ;  print $1,$2,$3 }' sslcheck.log | column -t

myserver1                         OpenSSL  1.0.1e-fips
myserver2                         OpenSSL  0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
```

I want everything to be deleted in the last column after char+hyphen(e-)..

Desired output..

```
myserver1                         OpenSSL  1.0.1
myserver2                         OpenSSL  0.9.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use awk sub-string function to extract the first three characters from the column three.

```
# awk '/out: OpenSSL/ { gsub( /[][]|out:/ , "" ) ;  print $1,$2,substr($3,0,3)}' sslcheck.log | column -t
```